# Understanding Maven scoping better

Tags: maven

I have been struggling to figure out what's the use of scoping that is provided by Maven
as mentioned [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope).

Why should you not always have compile time scoping? Real life examples would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `compile` scoped dependencies are only used during compilation.

The `test` scoped ones -- only during tests. Say you have tests using junit, or easymock. You obviously do not want your final artifact to have a dependency on them, but would like to be able to just depend on these libraries while running your tests.

Those dependencies which are marked `provided` are expected to be on your classpath when you're running the produced artifact. For example: you have a webapp and you have a dependency on the servlet library. Obviously, you should not package it inside your WAR file, as the webapp container will already have it and a conflict may occur.

One of the reasons to have different scopes for dependencies is that different parts of the build can depend on different dependencies. For example, if you are only compiling your code and not executing any tests, then there is no point in having Maven downloading your test dependencies (if they're not already present in your local repository, of course). The other reason is that not all dependencies need to be placed in your final artifact (whether it's an assembly, or WAR file), as some of the dependencies are only used during the build and testing phases.

Answer (score 3):

**compile**

Will copy these jar files into prepared War file.

Ex: hibernate-core.jar need to have in our prepared War.

**provided**
These jars will be considered only at complie time and test time

Ex:
`servlet.jar` will be provided by deployed server, so no need to provide from our prepared War file.

**test**

These jars are only required for running test classes.

Ex: Junit.jar will be required only for running Junit test classes, no need to deploy these.

Answer (score 2):

Scopes are quite well explained in here:
https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies

As a reference, I copied the paragraph:

> scope: This element refers to the classpath of the task at hand
>   (compiling and runtime, testing, etc.) as well as how to limit the
>   transitivity of a dependency. There are five scopes available:
>
> **compile**
>   - this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths. Furthermore, those
>   dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.
>
> **provided** - this is
>   much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to
>   provide it at runtime. It is only available on the compilation and
>   test classpath, and is not transitive.
>
> **runtime** - this scope indicates
>   that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for
>   execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the
>   compile classpath.
>
> **test** - this scope indicates that the dependency is
>   not required for normal use of the application, and is only available
>   for the test compilation and execution phases.
>
> **system** - this scope is
>   similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which
>   contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not
>   looked up in a repository.

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of reasons that you might not want to have all dependencies to be default **compile scope**

1. reduce the size of final artifact(jar,war...) by indicating different scope.
2. when you have a multiple-modules project, you have ability to let each module have it's own version of dependency
3. avoid class version collision by **provided scope**, for instance if you are going deploy a war file to weblogic server, you need to get rid of some javax jars, like javax.servlet, javax.xml.parsers, JPA jars and etc. otherwise you might end up with class collision error.